# Which method to use for BCD division in VHDL

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I'm required to build a system (prime number checker) for my advanced digital electronics class that makes use of a 16-bit BCD division module. The module has been specified according to the following VHDL specification.

[image: VHDL Specification of BCD16butDivider]

I'm confused about the use of the buffer type for *quotient* and *remainder*. From the research I have done on the keyword I see that it can be used as an input/output vector where the output may be used in determining the final output. I also have a little trouble visualizing how a datapath for this system would look.

My major concern, however, is the implementation of the module I have found an example of BCD division from my searches here: [BCD Division Algorithm and Example Code](https://media.digikey.com/PDF/Reference%20Design/Digi-Key%20DDS%20group/DKAN0003A_BCD_Division.pdf). However, in their implementation, they make use of a 3-bit Adder. I don't think I would be allowed to make such an addition in my implementation. I can follow the algorithm that they used and I can adapt it for my use case of a 4 digit into 4 digit divider.

Because of this, I am having trouble deciding if I should convert my dividend and divisor inputs into their binary representation and doing repeated addition to find the result or If it is possible to do the BCD addition. I'm also concerned about the time that the system might spend doing division if I use the repeated addition method if the numbers far apart, say 9999 and 2. And the algorithm provided may have multiple iterations where the divisor is being increased. I don't think spending time in the divider is a problem but does anyone have any recommendations for a method I can use or can anyone point in a direction where I can get more information on how to implement dividers?

Comment: you might have a look at COORDIC as well. What your project needs is an introduction section listing the methods you've found, and their respective pros and cons. The arithmetic can be all parallel, bit serial, or digit serial. The algorithm could be shift and divide, add up, COORDIC, and I'm sure if you searched the literature, you'd find a few others. With only 4 BDC digits, you might be able to do a lookup table, you could certainly do a table per digit!

Comment: BUFFER is output only. The difference from OUT is that the output value can also be used inside the component while OUT is a pure output. (Many people didn't fully understand BUFFER and tools would issue unnecessary and spurious warnings aboui it, so in VHDL-2008 the specification for OUT was relaxed to allow the port value to be used internally. NOTE your ENTITY specification is faulty; the END name doesn't match the entity name.

Comment: `they make use of a 3-bit Adder` Digikey's example uses a *3-**digit**
BCD adder* to divide by a 2-digit divisor; you start out with a 4-digit divisor.